# Can't restore my Notes

Tags: itunes, icloud, iphone

I've updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 6.1 today.

I made a clean restore in order for it to be as fast and clean as possible, without any junk leftovers.

The problem is that while I was able to restore all of my files, it somehow destroyed my Notes, I can't restore them!

#### Steps I did so far:

1. iCloud backup - In the iCloud main menu, I marked "notes", in Storage, marked the iCloud backup, then "backup now". (It went down from 5 to 4.8GB).
2. Normal iTunes backup to the device.

Please note I did that **before** the update.

When I finally updated, I entered my iCloud account, it took a long while, but when it was done, everything was restored **except** for the notes.

When I tried to restore the iTunes back, my last backup did not appear in the list!

I'm really at a loss please help me, I promise free cookies for whoever helps me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any email accounts, other than your iCloud account? If so, go to "Mail, Contacts, and Calender" in the Settings app on your iOS device. Find or add your email account, tap  on it, and set the slider for notes to "On." Your notes should be restored!

Comment: i try in a moment

Comment: I just added instructions how to enable notes for those accounts, as the Backup and Restore option doesn't actually restore notes. Notes are stored on a server, not on a device.

Comment: Should I see them in GMAIL or in the iphone?

Comment: You literally saved my life!